# Azure Rest API " Resource not found for the segment 'messages?$filter=From'. "

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to access messages for a specific folder which used to work. For some reason passing "?" in the url is rejected as "illegal character" in our api so I I have encoded the "?" to "%3F" and the final url looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders/INBOX/messages?$filter=From/EmailAddress/Address eq 'alerts-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com'
```

The header contains the following.

```
("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
("Content-Type", "application/json")
("Accept", "application/json")
("grant_type", "client_credentials")
```

I am using v1 of the Azure REST API as you can see. I can't understand what's happening.

Error I received.

```
{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Resource not found for the segment 'messages?$filter=From'.",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "d2e9b359-d40d-4c0a-a0a5-b4e3cf4b5ecd",
"date": "2017-03-24T14:35:28"
}
}
}
```

I appericiate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't encode the `?` as `%3F`, that breaks it. By encoding it that way, you're indicating that it's not the query parameter separator, so the server is trying to find a segment called `messages?$filter=From` :).

Answer (score -3):

I think the issue here is capitalization issues.

If you look at the query you have copied above, you have capitalized:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders/INBOX/messages?$filter=**F**rom/**E**mailAddress/**A**ddress eq 'alerts-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com'

When these 3 letters need to all be lowercase (sample below from [our documents](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/query_parameters)):

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'jon@contoso.com'`

Comment: Nah. That's not correct. #1. It used to work. #2. I tried your solution and same problem